# Detect offending text in MVC model binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, sql-injection, model-binding

I am using MVC 5. I find that text input that contains email addresses written as `John Doe<john.doe@example.com>` is detected as malicious text and is not submitted to the controller. This is a great security feature.

However, the problem is that the form remains frozen, i.e. the user gets no indication that some specific text is blocking form submission. I would like to be able to alert the user about the offending text so they can potentially correct it. For example, when including email addresses, I find that writing the address as John Doe(john.doe@example.com) is a simple fix and leads to successful model binding and form submission.

How to detect the specific instances of text input that MVC detects as potentially malicious text and give the user some indication to fix input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular express to validate email address. Enable client side validation, so user will get message when s/he tried to enter such characters.